# What directory will FileOutputStream save my simple file in(Android)? How do I find out if it has saved?

Tags: android

I'm trying to recreate a simple text editing Android app and so far I have this code to save the file:

```
                String filename = "myfile";                 
                String content = edit.getText().toString();
                FileOutputStream outputStream;

                try {
                    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename,
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

However I have no idea where in the internal storage this is being saved. How can I access/look at this directory to confirm the file has actually saved. I cant seem to find the file in File explorer in Eclipse (Heck, I can't even find the app name).Also, how would I go about loading this file once it is located? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openFileOutput(filename,
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` is application private directory output stream api. Your file will saved in your `/data/data/your_packagename` directory.

Comment: Okay. Does this mean I cannot access the internal folders of app_name outside of my app (i.e. is file explorer in eclipse considered outside of my app)? Is it possible to save a shortcut to files on my phones homepage?

Comment: your asking completely irrelevent question, at the first ecplise is a  just IDE(integrated development environment), like eclipse lots of ides are a available. here im talking about mobile_phone environment more precisely application specific how application lives its life in side the mobile dealing with memory and privacy. data/data is the application own data, so it will not be shared, shortcut links its no ware comes in picture.